# flatpickr angular 9 calendar alignment problem

Tags: css, angular, flatpickr

I created date component in my angular project. flatpickr is working correctly. Even if I set position as below in the config, when test responsivity of the screen, flatpickr is aligned automatically top of the screen. How can I fix it? How can I align it's position to below of input?

Answer (score 0):

check the dom if the inside flatpikr tag the 2 div are showing or not if not then set alignmemnt to the html element

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31149658)